# CX_Freeze and guiqwt works on windows not on linux

Tags: linux, cx-freeze

I use CX_Freeze to freeze one of my python programs. The build system works fine in windows. I can create a directory with executable and necessary dependencies that will run in any windows system.

When I try the same in Linux, the building part

```
python setup.py
```

works fine. But when I try to run the built executable, its gives the following error.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
exec code in m.__dict__
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guidata/__init__.py", line 540, in <module>
import guidata.config
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guidata/config.py", line 19, in <module>
add_image_module_path("guidata", "images")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guidata/configtools.py", line 100, in add_image_module_path
add_image_path(get_module_data_path(modname, relpath=relpath), subfolders)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guidata/configtools.py", line 86, in add_image_path
for fileobj in os.listdir(path):
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/user/tmp/dist/library.zip/guidata/images'
```

It seems that guidata is trying to find images under non-existing library.zip/guidata/images directory. I made sure that I run same versions of guidata, cx_Freeze on both windows and linux. Any help to resolve the issue is appreciated.

Minimal example

```
import guidata                                                                                                                              
_app = guidata.qapplication() # not required if a QApplication has already been created

import guidata.dataset.datatypes as dt
import guidata.dataset.dataitems as di

class Processing(dt.DataSet):
    """Example"""
    a = di.FloatItem("Parameter #1", default=2.3)
    b = di.IntItem("Parameter #2", min=0, max=10, default=5)
    type = di.ChoiceItem("Processing algorithm",
                     ("type 1", "type 2", "type 3"))

param = Processing()
param.edit()
```

setup file

```
import sys
import os

"""Create a stand-alone executable"""

try:
    import guidata
    from guidata.disthelpers import Distribution
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError, "This script requires guidata 1.4+"



def create_executable():
    """Build executable using ``guidata.disthelpers``"""
    dist = Distribution()
    dist.setup(name='Foo', version='0.1',
           description='bar',
           script="test.py", target_name='test.exe')
    dist.add_modules('guidata', 'guiqwt')
    # Building executable
    dist.build('cx_Freeze')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_executable()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here's the answer to my own question. After much digging up, I realized that it is a bug in guidata and/or python's os.path module. What happens is this. On guidata module, in configtools.py file, there is a function get_module_data_path, that checks whether the parent 'directory' of a path like /foo/bar/library.zip/yap to be a file.

```
    import os.path as osp
...
...
    datapath = get_module_path(modname)
    parentdir = osp.join(datapath, osp.pardir)
    if osp.isfile(parentdir):
        # Parent directory is not a directory but the 'library.zip' file:
        # this is either a py2exe or a cx_Freeze distribution
        datapath = ...
```

Now the test

```
osp.isfile("/foo/bar/library.zip/yap/..")
```

returns True in windows but False in Linux. This breaks the code. Python documentation is unclear in stating whether this is a bug or the intended behavior.

At the moment I don't have a solution, but a hack. I changed the above code as:

```
    import os.path as osp
...
...
    datapath = get_module_path(modname)
    parentdir = osp.join(datapath, osp.pardir)
    parentdir2 = osp.split(datapath.rstrip(os.path.sep))[0]
    if osp.isfile(parentdir) or osp.isfile(parentdir2):
        # Parent directory is not a directory but the 'library.zip' file:
        # this is either a py2exe or a cx_Freeze distribution
        datapath = ...
```

and everything is fine.